# GULP: Cleanup unwanted markup in SVG

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have multiple SVG icons, here is the example of one of the icons that needs to be cleaned up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="144px" height="144px" viewBox="0 0 144 144" enable-background="new 0 0 144 144" xml:space="preserve">
<rect x="32" y="32" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" width="80" height="80"/>
</svg>
```

I would like to retain `<svg>` and remove rest of the code. I like to remove just this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

I have done nothing but this:

```
gulp.task('buildSvgIcon', function() {
  return gulp.src([ paths.svgIcons + '*.svg'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/assets/cleaned-up-svg-icons/'));
});
```

Comment: Check out [gulp-svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgo). It's a gulp wrapper for the excellent, and very configurable, SVG-optimization tool [svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo).

Comment: @Jordan that was very helpful comment, please add it as answer, I can mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! I've written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great Node.js module for optimizing SVG files called [SVGO](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo), and it has a corresponding Gulp plugin called, predictably, [gulp-svgo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgo). I haven't used the latter, but I've used the former (with Webpack) and recommend it.

It looks like the options you'll want are (per the [SVGO README](https://github.com/svg/svgo#what-it-can-do)) `removeXMLProcInst`, `removeComments`, and `removeDoctype`. All of these are enabled by default, so this ought to be all you need:

```sh
$ npm install --save-dev gulp-svgo
```

...then:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var svgo = require('gulp-svgo');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('src/img/*')
    .pipe(svgo())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/img'));
});
```

If you *only* want to use those three optimizations, and none of the other default optimizations, you would do this instead (I think):

```
gulp.src('src/img/*')
  .pipe(svgo({
    removeXMLProcInst: true,
    removeComments: true,
    removeDoctype: true
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dest/img'));
```